# axios call whenever data added

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm creating a piggy bank app where I need to refresh datas when I add or withdraw funds.

I've tried using UseEffect with my API call with my actual state as dependencie but it is spamming the network with requests.

I'm not sure how I can "watch" new datas coming in the state without that spamming thing.

```
    // Import
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { axiosInstance } from 'src/components/App';


// Component
function PotDetails() {
  
  const params = useParams();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [potDatas, setPotDatas] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    axiosInstance.get(`/pots/${params.id}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        setPotDatas(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

So actually, i'm getting pot ID from URL using UseParams and then fetch datas from API pots endpoint with the ID I got from URL.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the array in useEffect is empty it will only trigger when the component mounts. Since you use params.id in use effect you could add it as a dependency this will get useEffect to trigger when `params.id` changes

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    axiosInstance.get(`/pots/${params.id}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        setPotDatas(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
      });
  }, [params.id]);
```

Comment: But what if I stay in the same page ? I forgot to mention that i'm using a simple modal form with the amount I want to add to the pot and when I submit, I want the data to dynamically change (without page  reload or changing URL)

Comment: Could you share that code then?
I do not see any issue with transferring that information from a modal to the parent state with a function.

Comment: I found a solution (kind of, there's still a minor bug) : 
My 2 functions (add/withdraw funds) werent modifying state. Now that they do, I added their states as dependencies for my useEffect.
Datas are rendering correctly but if I try to use the same function twice with same amount, the render doesnt work.